# RSA public and private key as String variables in Java

Tags: java, security

For obvious security reasons i need to encrypt and decrypt User's PIN codes with RSA private and public key, I have found working solution, which looks like:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair rsaKeyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
    byte[] txt = "This is a secret message.".getBytes();
    System.out.println("Original clear message: " + new String(txt));

    // encrypt
    Cipher cipher;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaKeyPair.getPublic());
        txt = cipher.doFinal(txt);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + new String(txt));

    // decrypt
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rsaKeyPair.getPrivate());
        txt = cipher.doFinal(txt);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + new String(txt));

}
```

everything works fine, but in this example key-pair is not static and generate new values everytime, but I need to use same keys, which are represented as String variables:

```
public static final String PrivateKey = "MIICXAIBAAKBgQDx0PSJr6zEP9914k1eM+sS8/eW+FenhBQI/jf6ARe8kZHFig9Y"
            + bla bla bla
            + "wdK3jBzObK319yNFr/2LukNZ9Bgv7fS78roBvxbe2gI=";

    public static final String PublicKey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDx0PSJr6zEP9914k1eM+sS8/eW"
            + bla bla bla
            + "jYo5w2Nhxe2cukCQMQIDAQAB";
```

Is there any way to cast these variables to PublicKey and PrivateKey Class?

Comment: `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` are not classes, they are interfaces you implement.

Comment: You should never encrypt passwords. Passwords should be salted ans hashed.

Comment: @EddyG I don't see a problem. A 'static key' in this context clearly means a crypto key(pair) that doesn't change for each run and/or call of the program; it has nothing directly to do with Java 'static' field, method, or nested-class. Putting a 'long-term' key in the source code at all is dubious, but if you do using `static final String` is reasonable.

Comment: You might want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, to obtain PublicKey and PrivateKey instances from your static variables you can do, for example, this way:

```
private static final String privateKeyString = "...";
private static PrivateKey privateKey;
private static final String publicKeyString = "...";
private static PublicKey publicKey;
static {
    KeyFactory kf;
    try {
        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        byte[] encodedPv = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyString);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPv = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPv);
        privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPv);

        byte[] encodedPb = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyString);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecPb = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedPb);
        publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpecPb);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this running doing the following:

```java
 public Key loadPrivateKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec =
        new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(stored.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
  }

  public Key loadPublicKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stored.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return fact.generatePublic(spec);
  }
```

You must also to remove `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`,  `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` and all `\n` from the strings that contain you keys.

Answer (score 0):

After (mostly) concurring with @JB that passwords (usually) shouldn't be encrypted, they should be "hashed" -- using a method specifically designed to "stretch" *and* salt such as scrypt, not a fast hash like SHA-1 -- and also noting that RSA-512 as used in your original code is broken and even RSA-1024 as apparently used in your modification is considered weak:

Your PrivateKey value appears (from its beginning) to be base64 of a plain PKCS#1 DER encoding, which basically is used only by OpenSSL and things that use OpenSSL (format) like older versions of OpenSSH. The Java standard "Sun" providers do not handle this, although I think BouncyCastle might if you want to explore that. For Sun you need to convert it to binary DER from base64; wrap it into PKCS#8 format (which in binary is just adding a header and maybe EOC trailers because the algorithm-specific *part* of PKCS#8 for RSA *is* PKCS#1); and put it in a `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` and run it through `generatePrivate` of a `KeyFactory` of type RSA. See

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html (Java8 only)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#section-5 for the structure of unencrypted PKCS#8 (Java doesn't do the encrypted format in section 6) and look at the publickey form for the OID for RSA.

Alternatively add the header/trailer to make it proper PEM, use OpenSSL to convert it to PKCS#8 (unencrypted), and optionally binary at the same time, and run that through `generatePrivate`.

Your PublicKey similarly appears to be base64 of an X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo encoding, which OpenSSL (but not OpenSSH) uses and standard Java *does* support under the name "X.509". So just convert from base64 to binary, put in an `X509EncodedKeySpec`, and run through `generatePublic` of the RSA `KeyFactory`. Note if your encryption will be done remote or distributed, which is the usual scenario for publickey-encryption, the encryptor must be certain to use the correct publickey; if an attacker can substitute a wrong publickey they can decrypt and steal at least some of your supposedly secure data. That's why real PK systems don't use a plain publickey, they use a certificate, either X.509 like SSL/TLS and S/MIME, or web-of-trust like PGP.